# Exporting Framer X to React Native

Tags: react-native, framerjs

Has anyone had any luck exporting Framer X prototypes to RN-consumable JSX? All I want is to export the UI prototype and animations that I made using Framer, so I can implement the logic using RN.

My current inclination is to open the TSX code for every single component in Framer, and copy-paste that code into my RN project with necessary changes. Seems like it's a lot more work that ideally should be? I also suspect that doing so wouldn't help with preserving animations coded in Framer?

Comment: What is your current situation :) Dreaming same workflow :)